# Mod_rewrite not working on localhost Apache/2.4.17

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have been try to rewrite clen url in Apache/2.4.17 i use bellow code and is working fine online but does't work in localhost

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /my_website_dir/
#remove extention
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ $1.php  [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /userprofile\.php\?u=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /userprofile/u/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^userprofile/u/([^/]+)/?$ /userprofile.php?u=$1 [L]
```

Above code show this

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.23

Now i also tried this only in localhost and it worked but not correctly

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /my_website_dir/
#remove extention
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ $1.php  [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ userprofile.php?u=$1 [L]
```

Here is what i get
localhost/my_website_dir/userprofile/u/peter
when i want to get the parameter value of u i get this `userprofile/u/peter` but i only need to return **peter** in `echo $_GET['u']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your last line with:

```
RewriteRule ^userprofile/u/([^/]+)/?$ userprofile.php?u=$1 [L]
```

Comment: in which one? if first one i did it already and is not working @Croises

Comment: sorry is working, What actually is the cause can you explain in your answer?

Comment: Your first link with `/` before `userprofile.php` points to the root not rewritebase. And after you rewrite from root not from `userprofile/u/`.

Comment: please help me in addition, i just find out the i lost all my css  when the page load so even when i  added / at the back of my css link now look like this `/userprofile/u/css/styles.css` insead of `/css/style.css`

Comment: Add `<base href="/">` in your HTML <head>